# Laravel auth request takes too long

Tags: laravel, authentication, eloquent, response

I'm facing very slow loading on every page even in production, like 5-7 seconds only rendering page and I don't know why. I'm thinking it has something to do with external Firebird database I'm using.

I downloaded laravel debugbar and came across this:
[image]

CISELPOD_UZIV_WEB is my users table and as you can see the simple query takes over 2 seconds. Any subsequential query is much faster. Anybody know why this is happening?

I'm using laravel livewire, connecting to external Firebird database, CISELPOD_UZIV_WEB has only like 20 rows, while lets say IRSVOZIKY has 30k rows and is 10x faster.

In whole app im using Auth::user() facade function to retrieve user, never use eloquent model CISELPOD_UZIV_WEB.

Answer (score 0):

So after consulting with database manager we found out that after onnecting to database there were some security checks that took approx. 2 seconds. Disabling these checks everything is faster. Other solution would be to persist the database connection which I haven't tried, but it would still be slow on first request to database by app.